# Convert DataTable to CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, datatable

I want to be able to `Import-Csv` into a PowerShell table so I can edit each section with PowerShell script, e.g. `$table.row[0].name = 100`. `Import-Csv` doesn't give that "table" it makes with CSV file.

```
$tabName = "TableA"
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "$tabName"
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ColumnName1,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ColumnName2,([int])
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.ColumnName1 = "A"
$row.ColumnName2 = "1"
$table.Rows.Add($row)
$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.ColumnName1 = "B"
$row.ColumnName2 = "2" 
$table.Rows.Add($row)
$table.PrimaryKey = $table.Columns[0]
$table | Export-Csv C:\test.csv
```

I want a way to `$table | Import-Csv C:\test.csv` and have the ability to `$table.row[0].columnname1 = "C"` and it changes "A" to "C". Then I can re-export it after making changes.

Comment: What is your starting point (i.e. where does your data come from)? Do you have a DataTable object, or do you have a CSV file?

Comment: It starts as a DataTable object. I have a PS script that runs for 4 hours updating DataTable objects. At the end of the day I want to export-csv shut down the pc, and come in the next day, turn on the pc and import-csv into the DataTable objects and continue where I left off.

Comment: So do you need to know how to create a DataTable object from a CSV file and how to perform an update on this (using `.Select`) or just how to perform the update as you already have a DataTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export a `DataTable` object to CSV simply by piping the table into the `Export-Csv` cmdlet:

```
$table | Export-Csv C:\table.csv -NoType
```

However, by doing that you lose all type information of the table columns (the `Export-Csv` cmdlet can only save information about the type of the objects that represent the rows, not about the type of their properties).

A better way to save and restore a `DataTable` object is to [save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135455.aspx) the table as XML:

```
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter 'C:\path\to\data.xml'
$table.WriteXml($writer, [Data.XmlWriteMode]::WriteSchema)
$writer.Close()
$writer.Dispose()
```

and [restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135420.aspx) the XML into a `DataSet`:

```
$ds = New-Object Data.DataSet
$ds.ReadXml('C:\path\to\data.xml', [Data.XmlReadMode]::ReadSchema)
$table = $ds.Tables[0]
```

Make sure to export and import the schema along with the data, because that's where the type information is stored.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly and I am familiar with xml so this works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The result of import-csv, as you found, is not a .NET DataTable object. There is this function to convert to a DataTable called "Out-DataTable" https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd . I don't know that it can go both directions, though.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.